# SageMaker Script Mode Serving

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, tensorflow-serving, amazon-sagemaker

I've trained a tensorflow.keras model using SageMaker Script Mode like this:

```
import os

import sagemaker
from sagemaker.tensorflow import TensorFlow

estimator = TensorFlow(entry_point='train.py',
                       source_dir='src',
                       train_instance_type=train_instance_type,
                       train_instance_count=1,
                       hyperparameters=hyperparameters,
                       role=sagemaker.get_execution_role(),
                       framework_version='1.12.0',
                       py_version='py3', 
                       script_mode=True)
```

However, how do I specify what the serving code is when I call `estimator.deploy()`? And what is it by default? Also is there any way to modify the nginx.conf using Script Mode?

Comment: How did you ran the BatchTransform job?
I create model. But got ngnix.conf not found error @Austin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With script mode the default serving method is the TensorFlow Serving-based one:
https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/master/src/sagemaker/tensorflow/estimator.py#L393
Custom script is not allowed with the TFS based container. You can use serving_input_receiver_fn to specify how the input data is processed as described here: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model

As for modifying the ngnix.conf, there are no supported ways of doing that. Depends on what you want to change in the config file you can hack the sagemaker-python-sdk to pass in different values for these environment variables: https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-tensorflow-serving-container/blob/3fd736aac4b0d97df5edaea48d37c49a1688ad6e/container/sagemaker/serve.py#L29

Here is where you can override the environment variables: https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/master/src/sagemaker/tensorflow/serving.py#L130

Answer (score 4):

The Tensorflow container is open source: https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-tensorflow-container You can view exactly how it works. Of course, you can tweak it, build it locally, push it to ECR and use it on SageMaker :)

Generally, you can deploy in two ways:

- Python-based endpoints: https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/master/src/sagemaker/tensorflow/deploying_python.rst
- TensorFlow Serving endpoints: https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/master/src/sagemaker/tensorflow/deploying_tensorflow_serving.rst

I would also recommend looking at the TensorFlow examples here: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/master/sagemaker-python-sdk

Comment: Hi. Yup I've been building it and pushing to ECR previously. Was wondering if I can use script mode for convenience but still specify my serve script?

Comment: Says https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/tree/master/src/sagemaker/tensorflow:


SageMaker provides two different options for deploying TensorFlow models to a SageMaker Endpoint:


The first option uses a Python-based server that allows you to specify your own custom input and output handling functions in a Python script. This is the default option.


The second option uses a TensorFlow Serving-based server to provide a super-set of the TensorFlow Serving REST API. This option does not require (or allow) a custom python script.

Comment: Hmm. read that before, but now rereading it I think I might be able to do it that way.   The python serving stack still uses their own serve.py, but maybe I don't need to modify that to get what I want.